# How to achive this code in c# to post Xml

Tags: c#, post

```
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://abc.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $theXML);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$response = curl_exec ($ch);     
curl_close ($ch);
```

How i can acheive this in c# to post xml requrest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create object, uri is your url and than post it. 
xmldata is your xml file

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmldata);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
```